# How to write dask dataframe in influxdb without convert it to pandas?

Tags: dask, influxdb

When I'm trying to write data into influxdb using dask it doesn't take it as  dask dataframe object. I've to convert it to pandas dataframe and that is time consuming process. I'm using UDP method to write data using python script.

Comment: You would do well to give information about influxdb, what it is and how you go about writing to it; what your data is like, how it is partitioned, etc.

Comment: I'm using UDP writing method and also using python script to write the data. my datatype is dask.Dataframe.. which is not acceptable. If I use pandas then it writes the data.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't mean anything to me, but maybe someone with influx-python experience can help.